# Load configurable variables into a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the below configuration file

```
[CLIENT1]
drive='C:/CLIENT1'
client='1'
[CLIENT2]
drive='C:/CLIENT2'
client='2'
```

I am trying to pass in a parameter to my bat file from the command line that will  either be CLIENT1 or CLIENT2. The aim is to load in the drive and clientid into the bat script to change the current working directory.

Something like this

```
@ECHO OFF

set param=CLIENT1

for /f "delims=" %%x in (config.txt) do (
   IF "%%x" == "[%PARAM%]" 
      (
         # Load the next two lines of code to set the variables
         set var1=line1
         set var2=line2
      )
)

echo var1 var2
pause
```

I am having trouble coming up with the correct way to load in the variables after identifying I have found the record the bat file has been run for.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up writing the below script could somebody please review it and let me know if I could be doing this better or utilizing some functionality to make this script alot neater?

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set param=CLIENT1
set /A count=0

for /f "delims=." %%x in (config.txt) do (
   set /A count=count+1 
   if "%%x" == "[%PARAM%]" goto :break
)

ECHO didnt find it
goto :exit 

:break
set "drive="   
set "id="
for /f "skip=%count% tokens= 1, 2 delims==" %%A in (config.txt) do (
   if %%A==drive set drive=%%B
   if %%A==client set id=%%B
   if defined drive if defined id goto :exit
)

:exit
ECHO drive - %drive%
ECHO id - %id%
endlocal
pause
```

outputs:

```
drive - 'C:/CLIENT1'
id - '1'
```

I plan to hand something based of this logic out to a colleague at work and I want it to not be awful.

Thanks.

Comment: Change to this: `set "drive="` and this  `set "id="`. Then get rid of the count and total comparisons in your second `FOR` command and use this to break out: `IF DEFINED drive IF DEFINED id goto exit`.

Comment: I think I have got it, I have edited my answer is that how you saw it working?

Comment: You somehow missed this: Change to this: `set "drive="` and this `set "id="`

Comment: I took the set "drive=null" and set "id=null" out at the top of the script and this compiles and runs fine. Are they not functionally the same as what I have done here without 2 lines of code? Where should I be putting set "drive=" and this set "id=" in your example?

Comment: In this instance I would initialize my variables to be empty or in this case undefined.  Just one of my best practices. I usually do this type of `SET` command just before I am going to be using them in my code.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so in order to prevent drive/id being set elsewhere in the script messing this up just initialize them back to undefined. Makes perfect sense thank you for walking me through this.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q47707478.txt"
FOR %%a IN (drive client assign) DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF /i "%%a"=="[%1]" (
  SET "assign=Y"
 ) ELSE IF DEFINED assign (
  FOR %%v IN (drive client) DO IF /i "%%a"=="%%v" SET "%%a=%%b"
  IF "%%b"=="" SET "assign="
 )
)
IF DEFINED drive SET "drive=%drive:'=%"
IF DEFINED client SET "client=%client:'=%"
endlocal&SET "drive=%drive%"&SET "client=%client%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q47707478.txt` containing your data for my testing.

I simply used `sourcedir` and `filename1` to suit my testing - use a fixed name for `filename1` if you prefer.

`filename1` only needs to be quoted if it contains separators like <kbd>Space</kbd>. If it is not quoted, remove the `usebackq` option (which tells `for` that the quoted name is a filename)

first establish `drive,client,assign` to *nothing* in case they already have values.

Then read the file, assigning the first token to `%%a` and the rest-of-line to `%%b` using `=` as delimiter.

If we find the target string, set `assign` to *a value* - no matter *what* value, just *not nothing*

If the target string is not found, then if it has already been found (so `assign` is defined) then see whether `%%a` is one of the required strings. Assign if so.

If there is no second token (in `%%b`) then we've found the next `[sectionname]` and therefore we've finished the target section, so set `assign` to *nothing* to prevent further assignments.

Finally, remove the `'` characters from the assigned variables (if required).

Notes:

The `/i` in the `if` statements make the comparisons case-insensitive. remove if required.

The "overly complex" operation with `%%v` allows the returned list of variables to be extended easily (with matching changes in the obvious places).

The `endlocal` would dispose of any environment changes made by the routine since the `setlocal`, but the apparently-superfluous assignment (which **must** be on the same physical line) transfers the variables from the local environment to the main environment using `cmd`'s parsing characteristic.

If you want to return `id` from the value in `client`, simply change `endlocal&SE..."&SET "client=%client%"` to `endlocal&SE..."&SET "id=%client%"`

If you want to return windows-standard `\` for directory-separators (`/` is a switch-indicator) then add a new line before the `endlocal` line

```
IF DEFINED drive SET "drive=%drive:/=\%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will read it over to try and get a better understanding. Alot of concepts here to learn for me